# Behave parallel execution for API automation

Tags: python, api, python-behave

I have built an API automation project with 4 feature files and each contains multiple scenarios. If I run the same using the following command, its working perfectly in order. Is there any way to run all features at the same time parallelly? Please help.

```
behave --no-capture -f allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter -o AllureReports
```

Comment: Reference - https://stepupautomation.wordpress.com/2019/03/28/execute-tests-in-parallel-with-behave-bdd/

Comment: This document says that the packages are integrated with selenium grid. Here actually I am working on API automation test and not using Selenium. Any idea how to progress?

Comment: Here is what I've done some time back based on some solutions available on internet that actually didn't work well for me. Works for me on multiple projects already: [behave-parallel](https://github.com/automationleg/behave-parallel)

Answer (score 3):

We have been trying for a while to implement parallel test executions with behave (which is an amazing framework). Finally, we created our own wrapper on top of Behave, called BehaveX, that not only allow us to execute tests in parallel, but also comes with great reports and some additional features: 
https://github.com/hrcorval/behavex

As BehaveX is implemented over the Behave framework, with this wrapper you should be able to replace the "behave" executable by "behavex", and run the tests in parallel using the following commands:

behavex -t @TAG --parallel-processes 4 --parallel-scheme scenario

behavex -t @TAG --parallel-processes 3 --parallel-scheme feature

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).